# export data to excel sheet

Tags: php, excel

I have used some code in which i am exporting database table data to excel sheet using php. But whenever it downloads the file first it opens with a error that it is not in supported format. By clicking yes it opens and show my complete data but in the last of the sheet the footer is also displayed.

**Code**

```
 <?php

 if(isset($_POST['download'])){

 // The function header by sending raw excel
 header("Content-type: application/vnd-ms-excel");

 // Defines the name of the export file "codelution-export.xls"
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Subscribers.xls");
 ob_clean();
 // Add data table
 include 'data.php';
 }
```

**error**

[image]

**in sheet error**

[image]

i want to remove the footer from the excel sheet and the error in opening the file.

Comment: try `header("Content-Type:   application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");`

Comment: it is giving the same errors

Comment: "Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel" i have wrote this but nothing has been changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use library for exporting database value to excel 

https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/